# How can I extract data from an HTML table in PHP?

Tags: php, html-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

Let's say I want to extract a certain number/text from a table from here: http://www.fifa.com/associations/association=chn/ranking/gender=m/index.html

I want to get the first number on the right table `td` under **FIFA Ranking position**. That would be **88** right now. Upon inspection, it is `<td class="c">88</td>`.

How would I use PHP to extract the info from said webpage?

**edit:** I am told JQuery/JavaScript it is for this... better suited

Comment: @MisterMelancholy you could do this in alot of languages.   I would use a dom parser like http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ to get the information I needed.

Comment: Use a proper HTML parser.  Don't use regexes.  They are not up to the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could probably be prettier, but it'd go something like:

```
<?php
$page = file_get_contents("http://www.fifa.com/associations/association=chn/ranking/gender=m/index.html");
preg_match('/<td class="c">[0-9]*</td>/',$page,$matches);
foreach($matches as $match){
    echo str_replace(array( "/<td class=\"c\">", "</td>"), "", $match);
}
?>
```

I've never done anything like this before with PHP, so it may not work.

If you can work your magic *after* page load, you can use JavaScript/JQuery

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var arr = [];

jQuery('table td.c').each(
    arr[] = jQuery(this).html();
);

return arr;
</script>
```

Also, sorry for deleting my comment. You weren't specific as to what needed to be done, so I initially though jQuery would better fit your needs, but then I thought "Maybe you want to get the page content before an HTML page is loaded".

Answer (score 0):

Try http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/,

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
echo $html->find('div.rankings', 0)->find('table', 0)->find('tr',0)->find('td.c',0)->plaintext;
```

This is untested, just looking at the source.  I'm sure you could target it faster.

In fact,

```
echo $html->find('div.rankings', 0)->find('td.c',0)->plaintext;
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Using `DOMDocument`, which should be pre-loaded with your PHP installation:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/file.html"));
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$cell = $xpath->query("//td[@class='c']")->item(0);
if( $cell) {
    $number = intval(trim($cell->textContent));
    // do stuff
}
```